# How to Place the background image scroll upwards while editing (adjustPan/adjustResize)

Tags: android-softkeyboard

I have Struggled with the following issue..

I need an Activity Which have an editbox and a chekbox below it..These are placed at the bottom of the screen...I have a background image for this total screen..I need scrolling of the totalview(background image along with edit and check boxes) while with presence of softkeyboard...

At start It was looks good..But at the time of editing the image is Resize(shrink)/the image is overlapped by the edit & check boxes with adjustResize in manifest option...with adjustPan I could get something of requirement but the check box was still behind the Keyboard...I much tried with Scrollviews and include layout options but couldn't get the required....

Could anyone Suggest me anything regarding this..

Answer (score 0):

At last I found some trick to get out of this....what I did was instead of using scrollviews...etc...just I scroll  the Parent layout (`ScrollTo(x,y)`) to some extent upwards...Which works fine with me...